# R Leaflet custom attribution string

Tags: javascript, r, leaflet

When using the R `leaflet` package, how can I add something additional to the attribution string (i.e. the "Leaflet | ..." in the bottom right corner)?

For example, I how would I add something like "data source: ..." to the attribution text on this map:

```
leaflet(data = quakes[1:20,]) %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(~long, ~lat, popup = ~as.character(mag), label = ~as.character(mag))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an `attribution` argument to `addTiles`:

```
leaflet(data = quakes[1:20,]) %>% 
  addTiles(attribution = 'I did this, you hear?! Also Leaflet.') %>%
  addMarkers(~long, ~lat, popup = ~as.character(mag), label = ~as.character(mag))
```

I'd love to know how to do this with `addProviderTiles`, though, because that doesn't appear to accept an `attribution` argument :/

**EDIT:** okay, my workaround for using provider tiles has been to just use both functions. I *hope* it's not actually calling both tiles, since that's a bit of a waste of user bandwidth—but hey, it looks fine!

```
leaflet(data = quakes[1:20,]) %>% 
  addTiles(attribution = 'I did this, you hear?! Also Leaflet.') %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap.Mapnik) %>%
  addMarkers(~long, ~lat, popup = ~as.character(mag), label = ~as.character(mag))
```

Answer (score 4):

As @rensa suspects, their second option does indeed embed and fetch both tile sets. However, the setting a blank urlTemplate seems to stop it:

```
leaflet(data = quakes[1:20,]) %>% 
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap.Mapnik) %>%
  addTiles(urlTemplate = "", attribution = 'I did this, you hear?! Also Leaflet.')
```

Comment: Been looking everywhere for this, thanks !