# How can I remove attribution in leaflet map in R

Tags: r, dictionary, leaflet, attribution

I am working on a shiny application in R which involves maps generated with the leaflet package. I would like to remove the attribution from the map, or at least reduce the visible text.

I tried to modify the `attribution` value as explained in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44953146/r-leaflet-custom-attribution-string), setting it to `NA`,`FALSE` or `''`, but none of the options worked for me.

I know there is the option to remove the attribution when working with leaflet in Java, (see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192088/how-to-remove-attribution-in-leaflet)).
Do you know if it possible to import this functionality in the R code or if there exists another solution to tackle this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found an answer myself.

It is enough to set the `attributionControl` option to `FALSE` in the `leafletOptions`.

```
map<- leaflet(
options = leafletOptions(
            attributionControl=FALSE))
```

Answer (score 0):

`.setPrefix()` method allows modifying Leaflet prefix.

https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-attribution-setprefix

`attributionControl:false` removes attribution completely.